# Gtk object has no attribute 'ICON_SIZE_BUTTON'

Tags: python, gtk, icons, pygtk

I'm nearly new to python and new to gtk.

I just can't figure out, why I get this error message:

```
self.builder.get_object("checkstatus").set_from_stock("gtk-yes", Gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
.......
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'ICON_SIZE_BUTTON'
```

At the beginning I'm importing:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

So the problem is that gtk has no no attribute called 'ICON_SIZE_BUTTON'?
But when I look at the documentation it says so...

http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.22/class-gtkimage.html#method-gtkimage--set-from-stock

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there's a few things going on.

For GTK+ 3 which uses PyGObject, you use `from gi.repository import Gtk` and then use `Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON`.

For GTK+ 2 which uses PyGTK you use `import pygtk` and `import gtk` and then use `gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON`.

In other words, you're mixing up versions. PyGTK (GTK 2) was replaced by PyGObject and something called "gobject introspection" in GTK 3. Check out this tutorial: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html